# Use data from a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array "fruits" in myfruits.js I can't access to it. It said "ReferenceError: fruits is not defined". What I'm doing wrong?

```
function showfruits(fruits){
    console.log(fruits[0]);
}

$("#search").click(function () {
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = './myfruits.js';
    document.body.appendChild(js);
    showfruits(fruits);
});
```

Comment: `fruits` variable is not defined anywhere in the context of your click handler function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're invoking `showfruits(fruits);`, the browser is still loading the resource from the server. You have to execute this function after the script is loaded, setting an `onload` event.

Something like this:

```
js.onload = function() {
   showfruits(fruits);
};
```

You can check some **MDN** **examples** here: [**HTMLScriptElement: Dynamically importing scripts**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Dynamically_importing_scripts).